# Setting a Checkbox in ImageJ Macro

Tags: checkbox, macros, boolean, imagej

this is a basic question but I can't find the answer anywhere.

When using the run command for macros in ImageJ how do I set the checkboxes (that I'd see when running it manually) using the macro.

eg. I have:
run("Subtract Background...","radius=1")

But I want to automatically check the box for a sliding paraboloid, something like this:

run("Subtract Background...","radius=1","Sliding paraboloid=True")

Or is this a separate set command for each process?

Answer (score 2):

You can get those GUI commands easily with the macro recorder of ImageJ, see:

https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-31.html#sub:Record...

The option you are searching is 'sliding', e.g.:

```
run("Subtract Background...", "rolling=50 light sliding");
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot